# Do a Bank Account needs to be added to Account(Seller/Buyer) in Balanced Payment?

Tags: balanced-payments

Do a bank account need to be added to User Account (Seller/Buyer)?

I have tried creating Bank Account without adding it to any User Account(Buyer/Seller) & done a credit transaction to that Bank Account. The transaction is showing result as *Success*, but is showing **Account's** column value as **None** in transaction list in Dashboard.

Also have few other doubts related to Balanced Payment.

Is it necessary to *Add a bank a/c* to any *Merchant (Seller) Account* for performing any transactions(i.e credit).

Is it necessary to *Adding a card to an account* to any *Buyer A/c* for debit amount from buyer?

Is it necessary to *Underwrite an individual* to a *Merchant account* for performing any transactions(i.e credit).

I'm creating a mobile app(iOS) which will be using balanced payments for transactions between Buyer & Seller. Do I need to get both Buyer & Seller registration information and their corresponding Bank Account & Credit Card information for performing transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do a bank account need to be added to User Account (Seller/Buyer)?

Only if you want to credit or debit their bank account.

> Is it necessary to Add a bank a/c to any Merchant (Seller) Account for performing any transactions(i.e credit).

No, it is not necessary.  You can charge a credit card without setting up bank accounts.  If you want to move money out of escrow, you need somewhere to move it, which is most likely a bank account.

> Is it necessary to Adding a card to an account to any Buyer A/c for debit amount from buyer?

If you want to debit an account via ACH, you do not need a credit card on an account.

> Is it necessary to Underwrite an individual to a Merchant account for performing any transactions(i.e credit).

If you want to payout to a merchant, you have to underwrite them as a merchant.

> Do I need to get both Buyer & Seller registration information and their corresponding Bank Account & Credit Card information for performing transactions?

No.

If you need more assistance, hop on the IRC channel https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/?language=bash#support

Comment: Thanks that cleared out most of my doubts...will definitely hop to IRC channel if any help needed...